# Selection the second child node in xslt based on a contains condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to return the day of week that includes Tuesday in the tag g but I'm not having any luck.  I'm only returning the first child element but not finding the second.

Below is a sample of my xml:

```
  <a>
   <b>
    <c>value</c>
    <d>value2</d>
     <e>
      <f>0</f>
      <g>Monday; Wednesday</g>
      <h>Don't return This</h>
     </e>
     <e>
      <f>0</f>
      <g>Thursday; Friday; Tuesday</g>
      <h>Return This</h>
     </e>
   </b>
  </a>
```

I'm currently using this in my xslt:

```
 <xsl:when test="contains(//g, 'Tuesday')">
```

It only seems to be looking at the first g tag and ignoring the second.
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Sorry, this is the xslt which didn't show up in my post:  <xsl:when test="contains(//wd:Pattern_Day_of_Week, 'Tuesday')">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` expects a string as the first argument. In XSLT 1.0, if you give it a node set, it only converts the first node to a string value.

The expression you want is this..

```
 <xsl:when test="//g[contains(., 'Tuesday')]">
```

Note that `.` represents the context node (i.e the `g` node being tested)

Comment: That's perfect - thanks so much Tim!  I'll select it as the correct answer once it allows me to do so.